# C++ : Swapping template class elements of different types?

Tags: c++, class, templates, types, swap

```
template< class T1, class T2 >
class Pair {
    T1 first;
    T2 second;
};
```

I'm being asked to write a swap() method so that the first element becomes the second and the second the first. I have:

```
Pair<T2,T1> swap() {
    return Pair<T2,T1>(second, first);
}
```

But this returns a new object rather than swapping, where I think it needs to be a void method that changes its own data members. Is this possible to do since T1 and T2 are potentially different class types? In other words I can't simply set temp=first, first=second, second=temp because it would try to convert them to different types. I'm not sure why you would potentially want to have a template object that changes order of its types as it seems that would cause confusion but that appears to be what I'm being asked to do.

Edit: Thank you all for answering! Pretty much as I thought, swapping in place obviously does not make any sense, the request for the swap() function was quite ambiguous.

Comment: I'd pick a different name than `swap`. People used to using the standard library will think that `swap` is meant to exchange the contents of two objects of the same type. How about `flip`?

Comment: @Emile: I don't see this as a big problem. It's a `swap()` that takes __one argument__ consisting of __two parts.__ What could it do but swap those? What's unusual, however, it's that it cannot be (well, I don't see how, anyway) an _in-place_ swap. That indeed differs from the `swap()` we've come to know.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot swap ***in-place***, since `T1` and `T2` need not be of the same type. `Pair<T1,T2>` is a different type than `Pair<T2,T1>`. You have to return an object of a different type than the original one, so that has to be a new object.

What I'd do is this:

```
template< class T1, class T2 >
Pair<T2,T1> swap(const Pair<T1,T2>& pair) {
    return Pair<T2,T1>(pair.second, pair.first);
}
```

(There's no reason to make this a member of your `Pair` template.)

You could, however, add an ***overload*** for when `T1` and `T2` are of the same type:

```
template< class T >
Pair<T,T>& swap(Pair<T,T>& pair) {
    using std::swap;
    swap(pair.first, pair.second);
    return pair;
}
```

But this, as Dennis mentioned in his comment, might be indeed very confusing.

Another idea is to define a ***converting constructor*** for your `Pair` template, so that implicitly convertible types can be swapped:

```
template< class T1, class T2 >
class Pair {
    T1 first;
    T2 second;
    template< class A1, class A2 >
    Pair(const A1& a1, const A2& a2) : first(a1), second (a2) {}
};
```

Then you can swap like this:

```
Pair<int,double> p1(42,47.11);
Pair<double,int> p2(p1.second,p1.first);
```

But note that this also supports other, probably unwanted implicit conversions:

```
Pair<char,float> p3(p1.second, p1.first); // narrowing!
```

Comment: Going from an in-place swap to an out-of-place swap based on an overload seems like a real potential source of confusion.

Comment: @Dennis: I'm not sure what you're trying to tell me. `:-x`

Comment: You suggest providing an overload for when `T1` and `T2` are the same type.  But this overload provides completely different semantics to the original form.  `a = swap(b)` might or might not modify `b` depending on the type.  That's not something I would expect.

Comment: @Dennis: You are indeed right. I've added a comment regarding this.

Answer (score 2):

Swapping is possible only if T1 can be casted into T2 and vice-versa. If it's possible then you could write

```
T2 temp (first);
first = T1(second);
second = temp;
```

(Note that you cannot change `*this` from a `Pair<T1,T2>` into a `Pair<T2,T1>` with this `void` function.)

Answer (score 1):

As `pair <T1,T2>` and `pair <T2,T1>` are different types you cannot use swap on it. Swap itself also doesn't do much more than using a temporary variable when a build-in swap operation is not given (e.g. at `std::vector` has one). Howeyer you can create a new type using references. Or you use pointers, where copying is cheap.

```
    std::pair<int, float> a = std::pair <int, float> (3,3.5);
    std::pair<const float &, const int&> b = std::pair<const float &, const int&> (a.first, a.second);
```